# Issue with scrolling and position:fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I maintain a Web page that has buttons which are supposed to remain fixed relative to the window when you scroll around and/or jump to links within the page (one of the buttons takes you to a random link within the page).  I do this with position:fixed, and I reposition the elements whenever I get callbacks for scrolling/resizing/URL changes.  Code is below.

100% of the time on desktops, the right thing happens when I scroll or jump to a link within the page, and the buttons stay where they are.

But the behavior on Chrome for Android is:

- When I scroll *down*, the buttons stay where they belong
- When I scroll *up*, the buttons scroll away with the content
- When I jump to a link within the page, the right thing happens around 50% of the time.

In both of the broken cases, after the bug occurs (i.e., the buttons disappear), if I scroll down for maybe 10 lines, the buttons appear again.  The callback to reposition the controls *is* getting called in these cases (based on printouts), but it doesn't position the elements correctly.

Good news, though… this bug is easily replicated in the Chrome Developer Tools.

There are a couple of pages exhibiting this issue; an easy one to load is:

http://awesomesongbook.com/soundtracks/soundtracks.html

Any advice?

Code follows.

Thanks!

```
$(window).load(function(){

    $(window).scroll(positionScroller);
    $(window).resize(positionScroller);
    $(window).bind('hashchange',positionScroller);

    positionScroller();

    function positionScroller()
    {
        $('#scroller').css('visibility','visible');

        if (window.screen.width > 800)
        {
            $('#scroller').css('position', 'fixed');
            $('#scroller').css('bottom',10);
            $('#scroller').css('right',10);                   
            $('#scroller').css('top','auto');
            $('#scroller').css('left','auto')
        }
        else
        {
            $('#scroller').css('position', 'fixed');            
            $('#scroller').css('top',5);
            $('#scroller').css('left',5);
            $('#scroller').css('bottom','auto');
            $('#scroller').css('right','auto');                       
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a documented bug in Chrome for Android with position:fixed.  I have not yet been able to digest the specific scope of the bug.

The least invasive solution I've seen online is to add this to the element in question:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform : translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

...but that didn't work for me.

What did work for me is disabling user scaling (pinch to zoom):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

This is sub-optimal, because I'd prefer to leave user scaling enabled, but it does make the problem with position:fixed go away.

Answer (score 0):

Is it absolutely necessary to rely on JavaScript? Best way to handle in my opinion  is with pure CSS. Based on your code, you could use a media query to position the padding for the scroller.

```
#scroller {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:auto;
    right:auto;                   
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
}

@media all and (min-width: 801px)
{
    #scroller {
        bottom:10px;
        right:10px;                   
        top:auto;
        left:auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no attachment to JavaScript or jQuery, but when I use your suggestion, I get the same behavior... when I scroll up, the fixed components go away until I scroll down a few lines.  It's not that they stay fixed relative to the content; if I scroll up 1000 lines, I still only need to scroll down 10 or so lines to get the fixed elements back.  It's behaving as if *Chrome* doesn't re-position position:fixed elements on all scroll events, but that seems to fly in the face of position:fixed.

Comment: @DanMorris Mind creating a JSFiddle with your code so I can see exactly what you're experiencing. You claim Chrome on Android is the culprit, I'd like to try on my android as well and figure out what's going on here

Comment: Further data suggesting something else is going on elsewhere in my html: when I use the Chrome debug tools (on Windows) and point it to the live site, I am able to replicate the problem.  But when I use exactly the same browser configuration and point it to identical html running locally, I can't replicate the problem (everything works fine).  Hmmmm.  Has anyone heard of things that trigger Chrome's layout to behave differently in local and remote contexts?